JsonView in the controller give a 400
I use spring boot 3.3.  I'm trying to use JsonView
public class OrderView {

    public static interface OrderOperationView {

        public static interface General {
        }

        public static interface Process extends General {
        }
    }

}

I created a controller
@PostMapping("/accept/order")
public ResponseEntity<PrivateOrder> acceptProcess(@Valid @RequestBody  @JsonView(value = OrderView.OrderOperationView.Process.class) OrderChoice orderChoice)  {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(orderService.acceptProcess(orderChoice), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class OrderChoice extends OrderDto {

    @JsonView(value = {OrderView.OrderOperationView.General.class, OrderView.OrderOperationView.Process.class})
    private boolean choiceSimilarOrder;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class OrderDto {

    @JsonView(value = {OrderView.OrderOperationView.General.class, OrderView.OrderOperationView.Process.class})
    @NotNull
    private Long orderId;

     @JsonView(value = {OrderView.OrderOperationView.General.class, OrderView.OrderOperationView.Process.class})
    private TypeEnum typeEnum;

    @JsonView(value = {OrderView.OrderOperationView.Process.class})
    private TypeOrderEnum typeOrderEnum;

}

When I call the controller with this payload
{
    "choiceSimilarOrder": true,
    "orderId" : 1234,
    "typeEnum" : "BIG",
    "typeOrderEnum": "COMMERCIAL"
}

I get a 400 Error, but with this request structure
{
    "choiceSimilarOrder": true,
    "orderId" : 1234,
    "typeOrderEnum": "COMMERCIAL"
}

it works ok.
It's like if both enum are there,  there is an issue
In the controller, I specified the view Process so typeOrderEnum should be accepted.
I created a small test, if I use OrderView.OrderOperationView.Process.class, I see commercial otherwise i don't see it so that ok.
Seem like a config issue with my controller
public class JsonViewTest {
    @Test
    void whenUseJsonvView() throws JsonProcessingException {

    OrderChoice orderChoice = new OrderChoice();

        orderChoice.setChoiceSimilarOrder(true);
        orderChoice.setOrderId(1234L);
        orderChoice.setTypeOrderEnum(TypeOrderEnum.COMMERCIAL);
        orderChoice.setTypeEnum(TypeEnum.BIG);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);

        String result = mapper
                .writerWithView(OrderView.OrderOperationView.Process.class).writeValueAsString(privateRequest);

        System.out.println(result);
    }


    @Test
void whenUseJsonvViewDeserialization() throws JsonProcessingException {

    String jsonString = "{ \"orderId\": 1234, \"typeOrderEnum\": \"COMMERCIAL\", \"typeEnum\": \"BIG\" }";

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        OrderChoice orderChoice = objectMapper.readerWithView(OrderView.OrderOperationView.Process.class).forType(OrderChoice.class).readValue(jsonString);
       
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

No error with this both test
With this one
@Test
void whenUseJsonvViewDeserialization() throws JsonProcessingException {
    String jsonString = "{ \"orderId\": 1234, \"typeOrderEnum\": \"COMMERCIAL\", \"typeEnum\": \"BIG\" }";

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        OrderChoice orderChoice = objectMapper.readerWithView(OrderView.OrderOperationView.General.class).forType(OrderChoice.class).readValue(jsonString);
       
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

typeOrderEnum has a value, but Jackson put it to null, maybe is the way jackson manage when this field is not supposed to be there?
but why spring controller fail?

If I go just by the question, isn't the issue reading json to an object, Not the other way around? So test should be doing deserialization instead.

The exact 400 error would be very useful in this case.
Regardless, based on the provided information, a somewhat wild guess is that you are missing a comma after the following line which makes the JSON payload invalid:
"typeEnum" : "BIG"

You should be sending this instead (note the comma after "BIG"):
{
    "choiceSimilarOrder": true,
    "orderId" : 1234,
    "typeEnum" : "BIG",
    "typeOrderEnum": "COMMERCIAL"
}


just a bad copy, comma change nothing
